# Renewal process with inter-arrival time distributed as gamma: Model estimation

Tags: maximum-likelihood, poisson-process, gamma-distribution, renewal-processes

Let's start with the Poisson process:

If $N_t$ is a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda$, then we know that the inter-arrival time distribution is an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$. As such, the parameter $\lambda$ can be interpreted as the intensity of arrivals. Moreover, $\mathbb{E}[N_t] = \lambda t$. For the annual intensity, we can then write,

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(N=n) = \frac{e^{\lambda}\lambda^n}{n !}
\end{equation}
It is possible to find an MLE estimation of $\lambda$ for a given observation.

Now suppose that $N_t$ is a renewal process for which the inter-arrival times are distributed as gamma with parameters $\eta_1$ and $\eta_2$. Applying the Laplace transform method, one can find the $\mathbb{E}[N_t]$, which is a function of parameters $\eta_1$ and $\eta_2$. It is feasible to derive the probability function of $N_t$ in case $\eta_1$ is a positive integer. That is
\begin{equation}   
\mathbb{P}(N_t = n) = \sum_{i= n\eta_1}^{n\eta_1 + \eta_1 -1}\frac{e^{-\eta_2}\eta_2^{i}}{i!}
\end{equation}
I wonder if we can find the estimation of parameters $\eta_1$ and $\eta_2$ by using MLE through the above probability function or through the inter-arrival time distribution (which is gamma)?

Comment: Suppose we observe the following arrival times: $$1.2,3.4,10.1,22.4,30,44.1$$ Subtracting consecutive elements yields the following dataset consisting of inter$-$arrival times: $$1.2,2.2,6.7,12.3,7.6,14.1$$ We can regard the above dataset as a simple random sample of size $n=6$ from a $\text{Gamma}(\eta_1,\eta_2)$ distribution. We can compute the MLE of MOM estimators of $(\eta_1,\eta_2)$ using standard methods. Do you have access to these arrival times of your stochastic process?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In response to your question, I should say that I want to work with the catastrophe data set (for example, earthquakes for which loss amounts are available, but I am not sure whether I have the arrival times) In case we do not know any information about arrival times, then what we can do?